# Unusual Number of Requests Message

Tags: discussion

I often have several tabs open, sometimes for days.

I have started receiving the following and there appears to be no way out of it.

Is there some way to fix this so it does not happen?

The contact link also does not work, it requires killing all the tabs and it is most annoying.

Is this caused because Chrome put the tabs to sleep and now, they are all concurrently trying to phone home?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this before when my browser restored a session - causing a large number of SE tabs to be reopened during a very short time period. The temporary block usually times out fairly quickly and then all is back to normal (but the restored session may be left with many failed reloads). It's possible they may be using more aggressive methods nowadays due to their recent DOS attacks, so maybe the block lasts longer.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite.  How many is several tabs open?  Is this on a PC? What operating system?

Comment: @hardmath: Windows 10, x86 Intel CPU, around 20 - 30 tabs.